# Flutter video_player VideoProgressIndicator scrubbing doesn't work on IOS while paused

Tags: flutter, video-player, flutter-packages

using the Flutter video_player: ^0.10.9+1 package

example project (code to reproduce): [GitHub Link](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/video_player/video_player/example)

When trying to scrub through the video using the VideoProgressIndicator while paused, the controller doesn't update on IOS, but does work on Android

Videos displaying my issue can be found in the zip files near the top of [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/55817) page under "VIDEO COMPARISON"

The Android scrubbing is Semi-functional, while the IOS scrubbing won't update the video until the play button is hit

No errors show up on when trying flutter doctor -v